# Flask and jQuery '$' is not defined

Tags: javascript, python, jquery, flask

I am brand new to programming and I am having trouble interpreting this console error that keeps appearing when I try to create a login page. I have basic login page with email and password inputs and a flask route that displays login page and display input. I have followed a tutorial online to get this working, but I when looking at the console I get the following error: `test.js:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined at test.js:1` According to the tutorial this should work. My routes for login and login_submit looks like this

```
@app.route("/login")
def show_login():
    return render_template("login.html")      

@app.route('/login_submit', methods=['POST'])
def login_submit():
    """Log a user into the website"""

    email = request.form.get('email')
    password = request.form.get('password')

    user = check_user_login_info(email, password)
    print(user)
    
    if (len(user) > 0):
        name = user[0].first_name + ' ' + user[0].last_name
        session['user_id'] = user[0].user_id
        session['cart'] = {}
        return jsonify({'login': name})
    
    return jsonify({'invalid': 'Incorrect email or password'})
```

And the javascript looks like such

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('form').on('submit', function(event) {

        $.ajax({
            data : {
                name : $('#nameInput').val(),
                email : $('#emailInput').val()
            },
            type : 'POST',
            url : '/login_submit'
        })
        .done(function(data) {

            if (data.error) {
                $('#errorAlert').text(data.login).show();
                $('#successAlert').hide();
            }
            else {
                $('#successAlert').text(data.invalid).show();
                $('#errorAlert').hide();
            }

        });

        event.preventDefault();

    });

});
```

In my HTML if I add to my form `action='/login_submit' method='POST'` I get the output of jsonify saying login was successful or invalid
The html is very basic and looks like this

```
<script src="/static/test.js"></script> 
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <h2>Log Into Your Account</h2>
  <form >
    <p>
      Email <input type="text" id='emailInput' name="email">
    </p>

    <p>
      Password <input type="password" id='passwordInput' name="password">
    </p>

    <p>
      <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </p>
  </form>
    <div id="successAlert" role="alert" style="display:none;"></div>
    <div id="errorAlert" role="alert" style="display:none;"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be due to the placement of the Jquery import in your HTML File. You import jQuery after the `test.js` file which causes those kinds of errors. Import jQuery at the top and try again.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="/static/test.js"></script> 

  <h2>Log Into Your Account</h2>
  <form >
    <p>
      Email <input type="text" id='emailInput' name="email">
    </p>

    <p>
      Password <input type="password" id='passwordInput' name="password">
    </p>

    <p>
      <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </p>
  </form>
    <div id="successAlert" role="alert" style="display:none;"></div>
    <div id="errorAlert" role="alert" style="display:none;"></div>
```

Comment: Oh yes, this fixed the issue! But it is unfortunately not calling my /login_submit route it keeps saying 'POST /login HTTP/1.1' 405 error. EDIT: I fixed it by recreating file with update to url. Thank you so much sir!

Comment: Add the `event.preventDefault();` as the first line after submit event callback function.